# Ansible Helper Functions?

Tags: ansible

Can I write a "helper function" in ansible to set variable from a module result?

I'm pulling a JIRA ticket and registering into a variable, and I'd like to transform some of the variable names to something a bit more manageable.

Ex. instead of `{{ issue.fields.customfield_1158 }}` I'd like to put the value of that field into a variable called `{{ ticket_cpus }}`

Comment: You wrote a question "*is there a best practice*" (which is already [not so much on-topic on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic)), I see a request "write this for me".

Comment: ಠ_ಠ  Rephrased and answered... Not asking anyone to write anything, just a pointer to the right docs.

Comment: It's hard to figure out exactly how to do something with some frameworks like these, whose syntax revolves around YAML plus the intricate opinions of their designers. The question could stand to have some sample code indicating what the OP has so far, but the question as a whole seems like one I would want the answer to if I used Ansible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up stumbing across [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html). It accomplished exactly what I was looking for. I was able to take the results from the previous command and save them as with easily readable variable names.

Code snippet:

```
- name: Set Facts from JIRA
  set_fact:
    server_name: issue.meta.fields.customfield_11162
    server_os: issue.meta.fields.customfield_11169
    server_cpus: issue.meta.fields.customfield_11160
    server_memory: issue.meta.fields.customfield_11159
```